# Search query using Regex in Mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to fetch results from mongodb using regular expressions. For example, while searching for a username `amitverma`, I want to be able to get that result if i type `amit` in the searchbox.

I have searched around the internet for a solution and everybody seems to have got it working by writing code like this:

```
var searchterm = req.body.name;
        collection.find(
            { "username": new RegExp('/.*' + searchterm + '.*/') },
            [ 'username', 'status' ], 
            function(e, docs){
                console.log(e);
                console.log(docs);
                res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/json' });
                res.write( JSON.stringify({ 'docs' : docs }) );
                res.end('\n');
            }
        );
```

I still cannot get it to work. It gives me an empty array. Also, after replaceing `{username: searchterm}` to `{ "username": new RegExp('/.*' + searchterm + '.*/') }`, I can't even get results for the string `amitverma` which means this regex thing is failing.

Comment: Hehe. Sorry didnt clarify. I am asking why is it not working for me? and what do i need to do to make it work?

Comment: Take in account that regular expression is case sensitive in your case. As well show examples of documents within your collection. Remember regular expression can be very slow, so never trust external client to define it - someone can simply spam you with very heavy regexp requests that potentially can crash your server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the slashes from the `RegExp()` constructor:

```
{ "username": new RegExp('.*' + searchterm + '.*') },
```

The slashes should not be there, unless you are searching for two literal forward slashes.